# Remove tiresome <optgroup> in form builder in laravel collective

Tags: php, forms, laravel, builder

I'm using Laravel collective form builder for building forms. I have used select like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('module', 'Modul'); !!}
            {!! Form::select('module_id', [$modules], $data->module_id) !!}
        </div>
```

From the unknown reasons, the  tag appears in my code. I don't want it there, but I'm really unable to find a simple way how to remove it. Thank you for a help

Comment: what is your result?

Comment: Result of what? From this lines of code I am getting this result: <optgroup label="0"><option value="1">... and another options as I expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing the source code for the package and the tests we can see that the `optgroup` is included *if* the array passed is multidimensional, [you can see that within this test](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/master/tests/FormBuilderTest.php#L339).

Reviewing the code you've provided we can see that you're creating a new array containing `$modules`:

```
Form::select('module_id', [$modules], $data->module_id)
```

Which means that if `$modules` is *already* an array, you're creating a multidimensional array. This is what the `select()` method is receiving:

```
[
 [
   "a",
   "b",
   "c",
 ],
```

There's no key present so the array is keyed numerically, starting at 0, hence the `optgroup` `label` value is `0`. You should be passing a single-level array if you want to have a single level of options in your select, e.g:

```
[
 "a",
 "b",
 "c",
]
```

You can fix this by not nesting your array in another array, `[$modules]` becomes `$modules`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('module', 'Modul'); !!}
    {!! Form::select('module_id', $modules, $data->module_id) !!}
</div>
```